# IIS hosting ASP.NET MVC site gives http 404 for urls containing 'web.config'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis, web-config, http-status-code-404

Requesting a page from IIS (hosts ASP.NET MVC 3 site) with url containing web.config gives 404  error. Urls with app.config have no problem. Local Visual Studio development server has no issues with this type of urls.

1 - What are any other special words other than web.config, being handled this way by IIS?
In request filtering page/hidden segments tab this is the current state:

[image]

<strike>I guess these are not special words, because IIS handles words like bin, App_code etc without a problem.</strike>

**Answer:** I guess these are the words being handled by IIS this way. So these are the default words I think and this list is configurable (new items can be added to this list).

2 - Are there any quick fixes (like by web.config modification) to handle urls with these special words?

Btw, I am not trying to serve the web.config file. Url format is :  *www.mysite.com/es/web.config/1*

Comment: Are you trying to serve web.config files? If so, do you understand why that is a very dangerous thing to do?

Comment: No I am trying to serve web.config file. It's just a parameter to an action. So it is included in url.

Comment: **Q:** "Are you trying to serve web.config files?" **A:** "No I am trying to serve web.config file." Oh, I see now.

Comment: Ok then.... have you considered changing your url so as to not cause all kinds of weird framework problems? Maybe just drop the `.` ?

Comment: @asawyer I think that is the way to go. But what I am asking is (1 st question) what other words exist that may cause all kinds of weird framework problems.

Comment: @archstanton I'm not aware of any but that doesn't mean there isn't.

Comment: @asawyer I think I found the answer, see the updated question.

Comment: @archstanton isn't that the answer I posted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the IIS configuration under the `Request Filtering` section:

[image: Request filtering]

You can add/remove filters.
**However**, I do believe this is a really **bad idea** to remove `web.config` from it.

http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

> As you already shown a snapshot of IIS configuration. These are reserved folder & files in .Net application, so IIS want to preserve those for security.
>
> URLs which contain these strings as returned as 404 response only if these comes in before `?` AND exactly between 2 slashes `/../` OR at last. Eg: *www.example.com/bin/anything.ext* OR *www.example.com/folder/sub/web.config*
>
> IIS match these string anywhere coz, web.config can we at any directory level.
>
> If anything is with those string are there THEN page will be served by IIS. Eg: *www.example.com/bin-folder/anthing.ext* OR *www.example.com/sub/bin.html* OR *www.example.com/-web.confing/page.aspx* are OK.

---

**I recommend** to use some other words with these strings OR use at end of URLs with extensions, so that it will not come between two slashes.

Eg: `www.example.com/en-web.config/1` OR `www.example.com/en/1/web.config.aspx`

---

---

**Even then I have one Tricky Solution:**

If you really need these strings exactly without other words in URL THEN I recommend to `use URL-ReWrite.`. This may not be quick at whole but except 2nd step its quick and handy, coz second step depends on your application.

**1-** Add this rule in IIS at top level:

regexp match: *(/web|^web)\.(config$|config/)*    //`OR as your requirement`

re-write to: *handler.aspx?url={REQUEST_URI}*

```
<rule name="web-config" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(/web|^web)\.(config$|config/)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="handler.aspx?url={REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

**2-** In `handler.aspx` (or in any other language page) check the `url` GET variable and respond accordingly.`Request.QueryString("url")`

- Do it carefully coz here you are controlling security.
- I suggest to include the actual page content to response in `handler.aspx or handler.php` only rather then redirecting etc.
- Before including content verify URL first(by regular expression etc.), and include content hardcoded, do not take any part of URL in to variable and use that variable in response-inclusion-code.

**3-** After that at last from IIS manager, In a specific website go to request filtering->hidden segment tab and delete the desire string. Eg: web.config. This step can be done by web.config also:

```
<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="209715200" />
    <hiddenSegments>
      <remove segment="web.config" />
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Now, IIS will serve the page and your handler page will show the output with exact same URL in user browser.